# Who was Bruce Wayne's primary martial arts trainer?

Tags: dc, batman

Who was Bruce Wayne's primary martial arts trainer? (e.g. a person who took a guy who was able to fight as well or worse as an average human fighter, and turned him into a guy able to defeat numerous opponents hand to hand in the same combat).

In Nolan's films, it's Ra's al Ghul (in the guise of Henri Ducard, who seems to be a separate character in comics).

I'd prefer an answer which spans *all main continuities* (initial Batman, pre-crisis, post-crisis, New52, and any non-comics and smaller where the answer is different as well).

Comment: Though this answer hasn't gotten a lot of love, it does talk about the trainers of Batman in most of the mainstream comic continuities [Who were the 6 people who originally trained Batman in the New 52?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15623/2765).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Recent New 52 writings ([Detective #0](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_2_0)) have revealed at least one of his martial arts teachers named, Shihan Matsuda. His base of operations inconveniently located in the Himalayan Mountains.**

[image]

- From Shihan Matsuda, Bruce wanted to learn to further his martial art skills but also to control his body with complete mastery and precision.
- In addition, this training would purge love and joy from his life to make himself an instrument of protection and justice.
- Bruce's training did include weapons skill as he is shown slicing through coconuts, hard shell and all with a sword.
- The only other person officially referenced as a trainer of Bruce in his early years in the New 52 is [Henri Ducard](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Henri_Ducard_%28New_Earth%29). According to Batman & Robin #4 he taught the uses of brutality, deception and cunning against the criminal element. It was his training with [Morgan Ducard aka Nobody](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Morgan_Ducard_%28Prime_Earth%29) which causes the rift between Bruce and Henri. Nobody is later killed by Damien Wayne.

**Also See:** [Who were the 6 people who originally trained Batman in the New 52?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15623/2765) for other continuity references and characters.

Comment: It doesn't seem that Ducard would count - he trained Batman but not in martial arts. What about Pre/Post crisis and original Batman?

Comment: He did train him in physical confrontation, intimidation, and dirty fighting techniques, so they should count, perhaps as a form of martial intimidation. As far as other continuities, [Wildcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcat_%28comics%29), [David Cain](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/David_Cain_%28New_Earth%29) and [Kirigi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirigi_%28DC_Comics%29) are referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Wildcat and Shiva are probably your best answers.

Wildcat is the first major teacher, teaching him for a short while when he is an adolescent.

Lady Shiva teaches him for a short while after he breaks his back.

One could also assume he studied under Richard Dragon as well, like others in the Bat-family, but I don't think that it would be significant.

The reality is, Batman is generally portrayed as having several or dozens of masters, for short periods. However, Batman isn't really a physical character and fighting was not the point of his training.